# bpy Camera Stroke Modifier code attempt: Menu not showing, property not working

Tags: python, add-on, grease-pencil

I'm trying to create an addon that offers a sort of third option from the Screen Space vs World Space stroke thickness. Inspired by [this post](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/hwhbbc/?sorting=hot), the idea is that upon activation, and on every update when there's a change in distance between the scene's active camera and a Grease Pencil object with this option active, the script will get the distance between the object and the camera, divide it by a set base distance which can be set and modified by the user, and then set the Thickness Scale option underneath the Stroke Thickness dropdown to the resulting value.

Problem is, there are some gaps in my knowledge, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing because the menu additions I'm trying to create in the Data section of the Properties Editor just isn't showing up.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel

from mathutils import Vector

#Create property on grease pencil object. It should work as a checkbox over the stroke thickness text box of the adjustments subpanel on the Layers menu of the Data section of the Properties Editor. 
class CamSpace(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    use_CamSpace: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Camera Space Adjustment",
        description="Enable persistent distance adjustment for stroke thickness",
        default=False
    )

    base_distance: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Base Distance",
        description="Base distance value for stroke thickness adjustment",
        default=1.0,
        min=0.0
    )
    
    #Maybe it can be keyframed? How would I do that.

#Function to determine the distance between GPO and active Camera
def calculate_distance(self,context,obj):
    #Establish active camera, =active_cam
    if context.scene.camera:
        active_cam=context.scene.camera
        camera_loc = active_cam.location
    else:
        print("camera not found")

    obj_loc = obj.location

    #Get current distance from active camera, =current_distance
    current_distance = (camera_loc - obj_loc).length
    return current_distance

#Function to determine Stroke Thickness Scale
def calculate_stroke_adjustment(scene,context,obj, base_distance):
    
    current_distance=calculate_distance(scene,context,obj)
    stroke_adjustment=current_distance/base_distance
    return stroke_adjustment

#Update function for when a frame changes or the GPO or Camera is moved
def update_stroke_thickness(scene,context,obj,base_distance):
    for obj in context.scene.objects:
        if obj.type == 'GPENCIL':
            #call the function nest, introducing the next layer
            adjustment=calculate_stroke_adjustment(scene,context,obj,base_distance)
            
            #for every layer in GPO, bpy.context.object.data.layers[layer].line_change = stroke_adjustment
            for layer in obj.data.layers:
                obj.data.layers[layer].pixel_factor = adjustment
    return('FINISHED')

#Create options in Data panel, under the Strokes submenu, to activate the CamSpace properties.
#Use conditional text box under the property checkbox to enter, modify and store the default comparative distance to operate from, =base_distance.
def draw_CamSpace_options(self, context):
    obj = context.object 
    layout = self.layout

    layout.label(text="test")
            
    # Add the checkbox to the 'Adjustments' submenu in the 'Layers' panel
    layout.prop(obj.CamSpace, "use_CamSpace", text="Camera Space", toggle=True)
        
    #Add the input for the base distance property
    if obj.CamSpace.use_CamSpace:
        bpy.context.object.data.stroke_thickness_space = 'WORLDSPACE'
        layout.prop(obj.CamSpace, "base_distance", text="Base Distance")
        #maybe grey out the thickness adjustment text box while this is active.


class CamSpace_Panel_Adds(Panel):
    bl_label = "Camera Space"
    bl_idname = "DATA_PT_camera_space"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "data"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object and context.object.type == 'GPENCIL'
    
    def draw(self,context):
        draw_CamSpace_options(self, context)
    



#--------------------------------
#register classes
classes = [
    CamSpace,
    CamSpace_Panel_Adds,
]


def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
        
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.type == 'GPENCIL':
            if "CamSpace" not in obj:
                obj.CamSpace = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CamSpace)

    # Set up the frame change handler  (possibly redundant)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(update_stroke_thickness)
    # Set up the update handler for object transformations
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(update_stroke_thickness)
        

def unregister():
    # Set up the update handler for object transformations
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(update_stroke_thickness)    
    # Set up the frame change handler (possibly redundant)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(update_stroke_thickness)

    for c in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things, possibly:

At the end of the script, you should call register.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The property should be assigned on the type (here I've changed it to be for grease pencils only (not assigning it to each object of type GPENCIL):

```
bpy.types.GreasePencil.CamSpace = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CamSpace)
```

Then in the draw function, you have to change from 'obj.CamSpace' to 'obj.data.CamSpace':

```
def draw_CamSpace_options(self, context):
    obj = context.object 
    layout = self.layout

    layout.label(text="test")
            
    # Add the checkbox to the 'Adjustments' submenu in the 'Layers' panel
    layout.prop(obj.data.CamSpace, "use_CamSpace", text="Camera Space", toggle=True)
        
    #Add the input for the base distance property
    if obj.data.CamSpace.use_CamSpace:
        #obj.data.stroke_thickness_space = 'WORLDSPACE'
        layout.prop(obj.data.CamSpace, "base_distance", text="Base Distance")
        #maybe grey out the thickness adjustment text box while this is active.
```

But you cant call `obj.data.stroke_thickness_space = 'WORLDSPACE'` in a draw context (the prop can not be changed in this context).

So that:

[image]